# hook_nodeapi called multiple times with op='update'

Tags: hooks, nodes

I am using the media_mover module.  I added some debug code to media_mover's hook_nodeapi:

```
function media_mover_api_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  dsm ("entering hook_nodeapi.  op=$op");
  switch ($op) {
    ...
    case 'update':
       ...
       break;
  }
}
```

When the user edits and saves a node, hook_nodeapi is getting called *twice* with $op='update'.  Anyone know why this might be?

If media_mover calls node_save during the process of saving the updated node, might that cause hook_nodeapi to be called multiple times with $op='update'?

(I am using Drupal-6.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are spot on.

If a module calls `node_save`, `nodeapi` will be called either with `update` or `insert`, depending on what happened.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance to call hook_node_update multiple times if you use field collection items in your content type.
The call times depends on the content in the field collection items